# SQL Server slow select from large Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

i have 2 Really Big sql server Database tables for IOT Project

First TABLE IS Message (rows count 7,423,889,085 rows)

```
CREATE TABLE [aymax].[Message](
    [MessageId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ObjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__Message__TimeSta__3B75D760]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [GpsTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [VisibleSatelites] [int] NOT NULL,
    [X] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Y] [float] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [Message_PK] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [MessageId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Second table is MessageSensors , row count (26,359,568,037 rows) , this table have value for each sensor in message table

```
CREATE TABLE [aymax].[MessageSensors](
    [MessageId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DataSourceId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__AnalogDat__Value__5812160E]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [AnalogData_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MessageId] ASC,
    [DataSourceId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

my problem that  seek by time interval between 2 date time is really slow , also it became more slow if i select with message sensor data  , also when i use sp_BlitzIndex check from brentozar.com it say that i have

> "Indexaphobia: High value missing index"
>
> 1. [aymax].[MessageSensors]   (EQUALITY: [DataSourceId], [Value] INCLUDES: [MessageId] )
> 2. [aymax].[MessageSensors]  EQUALITY: [Value] INCLUDES: [MessageId], [DataSourceId]

I belive  that create this 2 index is  will increase storage alot ,  also will take too much time to be created ,  i need your advice for both table regarding index

my current indexes

1-

```
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_gpstime_objectid] ON [aymax].[Message]
(
    [GpsTime] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [MessageId],
    [ObjectId]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

2-

```
alter TABLE [aymax].[Message] ADD  CONSTRAINT [Message_PK] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [MessageId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
    GO
```

3rd-

```
ALTER TABLE [aymax].[MessageSensors] ADD  CONSTRAINT [AnalogData_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MessageId] ASC,
    [DataSourceId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

4-

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [MessageData_DataSourceId_IDX] ON [aymax].[MessageSensors]
(
    [DataSourceId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

any help please ,  i need to make a fast retrieve from message , and message sensor

**update**
while doing some investigate  i found that select float value will slow up the result too much  , from  1 second to 3 minutes

```
SELECT m.messageid, 
               m.objectid, 
               m.gpstime, 
               m.x, 
               m.y, 
               -- slow is here  if i replace md.value with md.messageId will return fast , md.value is float 
               md.Value , 
               0 
        FROM   aymax.[message] m  WITH (nolock)  
               left JOIN aymax.MessageSensors md WITH (nolock) 
                      ON m.messageid = md.messageid 
                      AND md.datasourceid = 425732 
                       
                        
        WHERE  m.objectid = 14099 
               AND m.gpstime BETWEEN '2017-04-01 19:46:18.607' AND '2017-04-10 19:05:18.607'
```

Comment: How data file structured for this table and index?

Comment: What is the bottleneck? IO/Memory/Network?

Comment: With tables this large, I assume you're using partitions.  How are you partitioning the data in the table?  What is the partition key?  Are you including it in your queries?  (If you're *not* partitioning the data, I would *highly* recommend you do so.)

Comment: How is max memory setup to that db?

Comment: How are you partitioning the data?

Comment: max memory is 100 GB Memory , database size is 3 TB , Database have 1 primary file group and 1 log file , i didn't use any partitions , any advice about how partitions will help ?

Comment: @Eng-AymanAbdulhamidElarian Partitions will physically segment the data into different files based on the partition key, and when you query the data, using the partition key allows the database engine to only focus on that particular subset of data without even needing to do a table scan or an index lookup.  For very large tables, this is essential.  They are easy to set up and help immensely.  The only caveat is that you will need to use the partition key in your `WHERE` clause for all queries (even if you don't need it), otherwise you will be forcing a full table scan.

Comment: What is your normal access pattern for `MessageSensors`? Do you normally query by `MessageId`, `DataSource`, or `Value`?

Comment: @ErikE normal  by messageId, datasourceId , or only message Id , to get value Data as value is the sensor reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1. Filtered index (filter by date and do not index old data)
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes.
2. Clustered index on GpsTime, MessageId (Espessially if you have no plans about another indexes). Requires rebuild your table.
3. Partitions (see @Siyaul's comments)